# How to use a replace string with reflect in HIVE?

Tags: hive

I want to replace a string from "\7" to "\1", my input file like this:

```
a\7b\7c\7
```

my other table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001', so I must replace "\7" to "\1".

I tried

```
select regexp_replace(value, "\\u0007", "\\u0001") from test_tbl where dbs="test" and dt=20131130;
```

but it doesn't work.

And I wrote a php script like this:

```
<?php
$strCmd = "hive -e 'select regexp_replace(value, \"\\u0007\", \"\1\") from test_tbl where dbs=\"test\" and dt=20131130;' > tmp";
exec($strCmd);
```

but it return some error.

Answer (score 0):

For replace in hive, you can use below query.

```
select regexp_replace(value, "\\u0007", "\\u0001") from test_tbl where dbs="test" and dt=20131130;
```

Reflect in Hive is used to call static functions. So, String replace might not work. Here I found some information you are looking for.
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hive.user/7712

You can try the [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4025) with reflect2 UDF.

Edit:

If your input has plain text as '\7' instead of some ascii character, then below query should work.

```
select regexp_replace(value, "\\\\7", "\\\\1") from test_tbl where dbs="test" and dt=20131130;
```

Comment: I try it, it can find "\7" correctly, but it replace it with "u0001". And I try \u0001 the result is same. I write a php script and write "\1" directly but hive return an error "org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#1" is an invalid XML character."

Comment: Once check these http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm
and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm

I'm not sure why you got the error. Can you please tell me what you are trying to do exactly. What your input file contains.

Comment: May be in PHP, the reference for unicode is different. Look at this article http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/

Comment: @MoreFreeze check I updated my answer. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I copy your cmd and run it, but it seems as same as origin, it replace nothing. That so weird.

Comment: If your input contains ascii character, then from hive shell '\u0007' should work. From PHP, try '\x07'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with "[transform](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform)" method and I wrote a simple php script that contains str_replace. But I found another issus, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334363/why-hive-must-split-string-with-01-b4-0-11-0-is-yes-after-0-11-0-you-can-s).

Thanks all guys helped me.