# Why HIVE must split string with "\01"? [b4 0.11.0 is yes, after 0.11.0 you can specified]

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, hive

There is some string in a hive table, I use transform method that replace some char, my mapper script like this:

```
<?php
$strFrom = "\7";
$strTo = "\1"; // "|" it works well
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while($line = fgets($fd)){
    $outStr = str_replace($strFrom, $strTo, $line);
    print $outStr;
}
fclose($fd);
```

my hive sql like this:

```
select transform (value)
using 'home/php/bin/php -c home/php/etc/php.ini replace.php'
as (v1 string)
from test_tbl
```

actually I try to [replace string from "\7" to "\1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320596/how-to-use-a-replace-string-with-reflect-in-hive/), but I find it seems replace correctly, but it just output the first column. One input like this:

```
a\7b\7c\7d
```

then it output like this:

```
a
```

yeah, just one column!

If I replace it to "|", it output:

```
a|b|c|d
```

So I am confused, why must hive split string with "\1"? How can I forbid it? I just want to get:

```
a\1b\1c\1d
```

Comment: Can you post the script you used to create the Hive table?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer in [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries).

- Data written to the filesystem is serialized as text with columns separated by ^A and rows separated by newlines.
- As of Hive 0.11.0 the separator used can be specified, in earlier versions it was always the ^A character (\001)

Thanks for all guys that seen this question.